# Freemarker encoding wrong

Tags: java, encoding, jetty, freemarker

I have project it's jetty server which use freemarker. I use russian letters in my templates and receive `?`. All subjects i have read before didn't help me.
I use in my code

```
.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

all my files is utf-8.

My Freemarker page genertor servlet

```
public class PageGenerator {

    private static PageGenerator pageGenerator;
    private Configuration cfg;

    public static PageGenerator instance() {
        if (pageGenerator == null)
            pageGenerator = new PageGenerator();
        return pageGenerator;
    }

    public String getPage(String filename, Map<String, Object> data) {
        Writer stream = new StringWriter();
        try {
            Template template = cfg.getTemplate(filename);
            template.process(data, stream);
        } catch (IOException | TemplateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stream.toString();
    }

    private PageGenerator() {
        cfg = setCfg();
     }

    private Configuration setCfg(){
        cfg = new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_20);
        try {
            cfg.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File("templates/"));
            cfg.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
            cfg.setTemplateExceptionHandler(TemplateExceptionHandler.RETHROW_HANDLER);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return cfg;
    }
}
```

But in brouser my page in windows-1252 encoding.

Comment: Are the `?`-s already present in the result of `stream.toString()`, if you look at it right there with debugger or such (not in the browser)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for idea `ddekany` I used debag mode and find out that Class Response that extends HttpServletResponse has "magic" method `.setCharacterEncoding()` which set Character Encoding in response stream